# load data into hbase table using spark

Tags: java, hadoop

When I am running spark hbase load in java I am getting the below error. I even added hbase-hadoop-compat-1.2.0-cdh5.7.1.jar in my lib:

```
INFO spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: New executor driver has registered (new total is 1)
16/09/30 03:48:17 INFO util.Utils: Fetching spark://10.0.0.223:35442/jars/hbase-hadoop-compat-1.2.0-cdh5.7.1.jar to /tmp/spark-57b9be92-b517-4324-a8af-ba497c3bf00e/userFiles-269840ca-2ff1-4656-967c-acaf24d139fb/fetchFileTemp2398929293889822085.tmp
16/09/30 03:48:17 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Stream '/jars/hbase-hadoop-compat-1.2.0-cdh5.7.1.jar' was not found.
        at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportResponseHandler.handle(TransportResponseHandler.java:219)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:106)
        at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportChannelHandler.channelRead0(TransportChannelHandler.java:51)
        at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:266)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.TransportFrameDecoder.channelRead(TransportFrameDecoder.java:86)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```